# Pass Multi-Line Text Parameter in Jenkins to Ansible Playbook

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible, jinja2

I have a text parameter in Jenkins that looks like so:

```
                text(
                  defaultValue: '''
                  - 'evn-111'
                  - 'evn-423'
                  - 'evn-414'
                  ''',
                  description: 'Add list of devices to create lab',
                  name: 'DEVICES',
                  )
```

I want to take this list of devices and pass it as a string into an ansible playbook.

However, when I pass this string into the ansible playbook like so:

```
extra_args = "-e devices=${ params.DEVICES }"
sh "ansible-playbook $extra_args deploy_lab.yml"
```

My output in Jenkins is:

```
ansible-playbook -e devices=
```

Followed by recommendations on what arguments I need to pass. **Can anyone provide suggestions on how I can accomplish passing a multiline parameter to Ansible?** Once I get the variable in the Ansible file, I have a template that creates another yml file using the multi-line text string passed from Jenkins.

My Ansible file looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    devices: ""
  tasks:
    - name: 'Create device file'
      template:
        src: devices.j2
        dest: "host_vars/devices.yml"
        mode: '0600'
      delegate_to: localhost
```

My Template file devices.j2 looks like this:

```
---
devices_from_jenkins_param:
    "{{ devices }}"
```

In the end, I want there to be a file host_vars/devices.yml that looks like this:

```
---
devices_from_jenkins_param:
     - 'evn-111'
     - 'evn-423'
     - 'evn-414'
```

Comment: As it's going in to yaml, why not avoid the issue by passing `['evn-111', 'evn-423']` on one line

Comment: Additionally, this looks more like the value is an empty string instead of a multiline string.